# ios - Swift2 "no such module" Pods Error in Xcode 7.2

Tags: ios, swift2, cocoapods

Can someone help my error about "no such module" pods in swift2

What I Did is that,

1. pod deintegrate
2. pod clean
3. pod install

but still isn't working.

[image]

Comment: set $(SRCROOT) in build settings against Framework search path header

Answer (score 0):

Add $(SRCROOT) in Framework search path header .

[image]